# jquery toggle showing and hiding different elements... confusing

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle, show

I've got a toggle set on an  element that I want to show hide 4 elements (3 ids, 1 class).

Here's my jquery

```
$('#tap-menu').click(function() {
    $('#left-column, #settings, #ortibi, .userprofile').toggle();
});
```

These 4 elements are hidden on page load and on the first toggle, show all of them. If I toggle to hide again, that's fine. But if I toggle to show them again. The .userprofile doesn't show. Is this because it's a class rather than an id in the CSS?

Why would that effect it?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What's the CSS for .userprofile? Does this element have any inline styles?

Comment: initially - display: none; and then it also has (when visible) - height: 56px;
 margin-left: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 top:  0px;
} no inline styles :/

Comment: You should supply "left:0". The rest looks good.

Comment: I am thinking that there is some conflicting style around there.. I'd want to look at your code in firebug to know what is going on ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `display: none;` on the .userprofile css, hide the elements with jquery like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#left-column, #settings, #ortibi, .userprofile').hide();
});
```

See this for more information: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Specifically:

> The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation.
>   This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'none'), except
>   that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data
>   cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value. If
>   an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it
>   will once again be displayed inline.

Conversely, if it initially has a value of `display: none;` toggling it back on will give it the same value of `display: none;`.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the 4 elements will be visible until the page loads.

Comment: I generally hack around that by setting a `height: 0px;` on the element to hide it, and then adjusting the height after I've hidden it with jQuery. Is there a better way to do it? I don't usually mess with  `display: none;` because it's easier to let jQuery handle it.

Comment: I usually have a class `.hide {display:none;}` in my css files which I use to initialize hidden objects. Then I use `.hide()` and `.show()` in the page js.

Comment: Do you use jQuery to remove the CSS class after you've hidden it properly with jQuery?

Comment: No, because jQuery's `.hide()` adds an inline `display:none` to the element, so that overrides the `hide` class css.